# How do I create a regex in Emacs to capture text between double square brackets?

Tags: regex, emacs

I want to create a regex in Emacs that captures text between double square brackets.

I found this regex. It allows to find string betwen square brackets but it includes the square brackets :

```
"\\[\\[\\([^][]+\\)\\]\\(\\[\\([^][]+\\)\\]\\)?\\]"
```

How can extract the string between double square brackets excluding the square brackets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This regexp will select the square brackets but by using group 1 you will be able to get only the content: `"\\[\\[\\(.*\\)\\]\\]"`

Comment: Thank you. I can check that your regexp works perfectly with re-builder. But, to be honest, I don't known how to use that. I just need this regexp to customize the [wiki.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/wiki.el) minor mode : (setq wiki-name-regexp "\[\[\(.*\)\]\]")

Comment: How would I match only the content between single square brackets? I tried `"\\[\\(.*\\)\\]"` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot.  Emacs' regexp engine does not support look-ahead/look-behind assertions.

As a work, around, just group the part you're interested in and access the subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

To extract data from a string, use `string-match` and `match-string`, like this:

```
(let ((my-string "[[some text][some more text]]")
      (my-regexp "\\[\\[\\([^][]+\\)\\]\\(\\[\\([^][]+\\)\\]\\)?\\]"))
  (and (string-match my-regexp my-string)
       (list (match-string 1 my-string) (match-string 3 my-string))))
```

which evaluates to:

```
("some text" "some more text")
```

To extract data from a buffer, use `search-forward-regexp` and drop the string argument to `match-string`:

```
(and
 (search-forward-regexp "\\[\\[\\([^][]+\\)\\]\\(\\[\\([^][]+\\)\\]\\)?\\]" nil :no-error)
 (list (match-string 1) (match-string 3)))
```

Note that this moves point to the match.